# Is there a way to localize role labels?

Tags: multi-language, plugin-qtranslate, user-roles, plugin-members

I'm using Justin Tadlock's Members plugin to create new roles and WP Role on Registration to display them on the registration form.

I've got a multilang site (English and Spanish) and I've localized my custom taxonomies using qTranslate.

I can't use qTranslate's quicktags in the Role Label field on the Member's plugin because it doesn't save it properly (even with `$new_role_label = strip_tags( $_POST['role-label'] );` commented out on role-new.php) and I can't go into the database to make the changes there because then it breaks.

I've seen very scarce info about the [WP function translate_user_role](http://wpseek.com/translate_user_role/) but I'm not sure it. There's not much else to go on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the function you mention either, but I would venture to guess that that applies to default roles only anyhow.

Still, the link you posted does contain a pointer in the right direction. It speaks of "dummy gettext calls", which is exactly what you have to do.

In the following we will adjust the global `$wp_roles` object on `init` and hook a filter to the `get_option( 'wp_user_roles' )` call.

```
function wpse92529_translatable_role_names() {
    global $wp_roles;

    $roles = $wp_roles->roles;
    $role_names = $wp_roles->role_names;

    /* define the translatable roles here */
    $translated_roles = array(
        'superuser' => _x( 'Superuser', 'Role Names', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'custom-role' => _x( 'The custom role', 'Role Names', 'your-text-domain' )
    );

    foreach ( $roles as $role_slug => $role_info ) {
        if ( array_key_exists( $role_slug, $translated_roles ) ) {
            $roles[$role_slug]['name'] = $translated_roles[$role_slug];
            $role_names[$role_slug] = $translated_roles[$role_slug];
        }
    }

    $wp_roles->roles = $roles;
    $wp_roles->role_names = $role_names;

    return $roles;
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse92529_translatable_role_names', 1 );
add_filter( 'option_wp_user_roles', 'wpse92529_translatable_role_names', 11 );
```

The values of the `$translated_roles` array will now appear in your theme's / plugin's `.pot` file.

Comment: Indeed it's a very helpful function, thanks for sharing! Anyway, I was wondering if is it possible to filter the user role names returned by `$wp_roles->get_names();` - If any plugin or theme uses the global `$wp_roles` object with along the `get_names()` function, it seems not to have any effect for the user roles names returned by those.